# core data simple fetch request template in swift

Tags: swift

Hi guys I fetched the data from core data using fetch request by programmatically ? my question is how to fetch data by using 
 fetchRequestTemplateForName ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is declare both **managedObjectContext** and **managedObjectModel** :

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let model: NSManagedObjectModel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectModel
```

Then you can simply use fetch request template that you created. If template name is "olderThen35" code looks like this:

```
let request = model.fetchRequestTemplateForName("olderThen35")!
```

Comment: What when I want to pass value at runtime? like older that X?